# Intellij warning no artifacts configured

Tags: java, maven

I have two classes

```
    package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

    package com.example;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

I want to make a springboot application that uses maven and tomcat. I want to see output in localhost page.

I use 8282 port, when i click run, it opens that page but it is empty.

So i created a war artifact. Web applicatin exploded but this time it says can not create artifact and it doesnot open that web page.

Why does it show an empty page? I was seeing the output before integrating tomcat.

This is output

```
   /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.2.0-30-generic
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_74-b02
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_HelloW
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.417 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_HelloW/conf/logging.properties
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.417 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.417 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.437 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/caneraydin/.IntelliJIdea16/system/tomcat/Unnamed_HelloW
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
05-Mar-2016 18:20:58.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/caneraydin/Downloads/idea-IU-144.4199.23/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.036 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8282"]
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.084 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.099 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.102 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1787 ms
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.218 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.221 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.236 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8282"]
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.336 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Mar-2016 18:20:59.353 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 245 ms
Connected to server
05-Mar-2016 18:21:09.252 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
05-Mar-2016 18:21:09.732 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 479 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

warning no artifacts configured
Select Artifacts from left, choose Web Application: Exploded (JAR is default?),then the warning disappeared, just for your reference,